# Close android Notification

Tags: android, notifications

i have create notification when service start but i have not idea how to close that notification when service stop or on destroy. have any idea.

following code that start notification when service start.

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    final int KEEPUS_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_icon1, ticker_text, System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, KeepusActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, ticker_content_title, ticker_content_text,contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(KEEPUS_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

use notification manager #cancel with your notification id

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.cancel(KEEPUS_NOTIFICATION_ID);
```