# How to close notification after some determined time without any clicks by user?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am generating a notification from a class that extends FireBaseMessagingService. I need to close the notification after a prescribed time.

Comment: check out postdelayed:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845172/android-running-a-method-periodically-using-postdelayed-call

Comment: you can just create a service that runs in the background that'll timeout after five minutes and delete your notification

Comment: If you want to do that even when app is killed you can achieve it by using AlarmManager by setting alarm after required hours of triggering notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.cancel(notificationId);
```

to clear the notification (by the `notificationId`). If you want to timing this operation you can use a AlarmManager like:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, CustomAlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
        60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```

put your clear method inside CustomAlarmReceiver class.

Answer (score 0):

If you stuck in trigger the close action after a prescribed time, there's enough suggestions in the comment above.

If you stuck in how to close an notification.
check this:[Close android Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533360/close-android-notification)